# Python Flask WTForms custom error if image size too big

Tags: python, image

I am currently working on a system to resize images before uploads. The problem is a user can upload up to 15 images which will be uploaded to amazon s3 storage.

If all images are too big, the request fails due to a timeout error. I have increased the timeout and added a progress bar but this is ofc. a workaround.

I also added a max size value to my app:

```
MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = 15 * 1024 * 1024
```

So the request cant be bigger then 15 MB.

If the image is bigger flask throws a 413 error.

What I need is that my form does not submit and shows an error "image too big max. size 1 MB", so I need to create a custom validation for the WTForms FileField?